# Element not visible with JAVA - Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

i have a problem with my code... When i try to make the login. in special with the password.

My code:

```
public static void VentaGC() throws InterruptedException{
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\BlackSinger\\Documents\\Librerias Java\\Crhomedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://foro-ptc.com/");
        WebElement login;
        login= driver.findElement(By.linkText("login"));
        login.click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebElement loginbox;
        loginbox= driver.findElement(By.id("navbar_username"));
        loginbox.click();
        loginbox.sendKeys("proof");
        WebElement passbox;
        passbox= driver.findElement(By.name("vb_login_password_hint"));

        passbox.click();
        passbox.sendKeys("pass");
    }
}
```

The error is this:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

In this line of my code:

> ```
> passbox.sendKeys("pass");
> ```

The site, is this: https://foro-ptc.com/ in login section.

If someone have an idea please help me! thanks

Comment: Why you are trying to click? send directly to input box

Comment: Nitpick: "JAVA" is spelled _Java_, it is not an acronym. [COBOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COBOL) is an example of an acronym that stands for "common business-oriented language". In English we use upper case letters to indicate an acronym for non-single letter words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is there are 2 inputs for password. Actual password input is one with `id="navbar_password"` and it not visible until you click on `<div class="navbar_password_outer">`. When you click input you used `name="vb_login_password_hint"` becomes not visible and you get `ElementNotVisibleException` error.

```
<div class="navbar_password_outer">
    <input type="password" class="textbox" tabindex="102" name="vb_login_password" id="navbar_password" size="10" style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" class="textbox default-value" tabindex="102" name="vb_login_password_hint" id="navbar_password_hint" size="10" value="Contraseña" style="display: inline;">
</div>
```

Code:

```
public static void VentaGC(){

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\BlackSinger\\Documents\\Librerias Java\\Crhomedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.get("https://foro-ptc.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("login")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("navbar_username")).sendKeys("proof");

    driver.findElement(By.className("navbar_password_outer")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("navbar_password")).sendKeys("pass", Keys.ENTER);

}
```

If you issue with open page for the first time you can add code below:

```
try{
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://foro-ptc.com/");
} catch (TimeoutException ignored) {}
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```